# Adding a log in asymptotic analysis

Tags: algorithm, logarithm, asymptotic-complexity

Have a problem I'm trying to work through and would very much appreciate some assistance! What's the time complexity of...

```
for (int j = 1 to n) {
    k = j;
    while (k < n) {
        sum += a[k] * b[k];
        k += log n;
    }
}
```

The outer for loop runs n times. I'm not sure how to deal with `k+= log n` in the inner loop. My thought is that it's O(n^2). Adding log(n) to k isn't quite getting an additional n loops, but I think it is less than O(n*log n) would be. Obviously, that's just a guess, and any help in figuring out how to show that mathematically would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many times does the inner loop execute? `ceil((n-j)/log(n))`. Work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat `log(n)` as a constant here, sort of.

Each iteration of the loop will perform a constant amount of work (`sum+=...; k+=...`) a number of times equal to `n`/`log(n)`. There are `n` iterations of the loop. The total work is thus `n^2 / log(n)`.

Any time you see a bunch of operations like so:

```
 ---------------------b-------------------------
 |O(blah) + O(blah) + O(blah) + O(blah) + O(blah)
 |O(blah) + O(blah) + O(blah) + O(blah)     .
a|O(blah) + O(blah) + O(blah)               .
 |O(blah) + O(blah)                         .
 |O(blah)     .         .         .         .
```

It is `a*b * O(blah)` -- just imagine the square (where I put the `.`s). It is a constant fraction of a 2D rectangle (half of a rectangle), hence the `O(a*b)`.

In the above case, b=`n`, a=`n/log(n)`, and O(blah)=`O(1)`(from the inner loop)

Comment: Thanks - one follow up. So the n/log(n) - you arrived at that just by looking, right? Is there any other trick or suggestion to discern n/log(n), other than just being better at math ;)? My problem is always figuring out how to translate the code to a mathematical equation, and I'm often surprised about how little help there is online regarding that fact.

Comment: Well it was a constant with respect to the loop (i.e. you could pull it out of the sum, if you prefer to think about it that way). If it wasn't `log(n)` but rather something like `log(j)` (for some weird reason), it would have been more difficult. I would start by just writing down the amount of work term-by-term, and trying to see a pattern. You could also simulate it to bound it ("oh, somewhere between n and n^2..."). You could rewrite it recursively and use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily "just sump up":

The outer loop has as you said `n` steps. The inner loop has `(k-j) / log n` steps.

That's (roughly):

```
 n
---
\     (n-j)             n*n
/   -------- = ... = ---------
___  (log n)          2*log(n)
j=1
```

So, it's `O((n^2)/log(n))` in total.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed formally like the following:

[image]